# How do I save a text file with the `.sh` extension?

Tags: shell-script

New to using .sh on Mac. Simple question - how do I save a text file with extension .sh? I've exhausted my limited knowledge. I need to do this conversion to test run scripts on OS X. Though, with what I've gleaned from the web, Linux is much easier to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are familiar with the cmd, use vim or touch in terminal(Launchpad--others--terminal or just Spotlight--terminal) just like you do in linux.
2. Use TextEdit to create a new document. After saving this document, add a .sh to rename it.
3. Third party textedit softwares are also available for suffix change.